# Excel VBA -extracting data from a .SQL file

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

We have a .sql (SQL Server) file which works absolutely fine is SSMS. We need to read the file and fetch that data into Excel using VBA code. This code works fine if I convert into stored procedure and call the stored procedure through VBA to populate the spreadsheet. But the challenge is that need to use the code in form of .sql file itself (since the user will be constantly maintaining this .sql file and does not have rights to alter proc on production server.)

this SQL code creates temp (# or table variables) tables. I even tried converting them to physical tables and then writing a final SELECT statement but it does not work. The error it gives is 3704 (Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.).
example:

```
    Truncate table  dbo.MyTable;
    INSERT INTO  dbo.MyTable  
    SELECT ...
    FROM dbo.ABC 
    JOIN dbo.XYZ...

    SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable;
```

Only having a SELECT statement inside .sql file works to get data in Excel using VBA code.

Anyone has any thoughts about it?

Comment: If i understand your code the problem is how to execute insert and select on excel connection.Did you try set nocount on; at the beginning of the file?

Comment: Can you post the VBA code? That is where the problem lies.

Comment: Just tried, it worked with small sql, but when I put the whole sql statement, again giving same issue. Also would like to point out that in messages it is giving: Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
Could this be causing it to fail?

Comment: I put SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF; along with SET NOCOUNT ON; and it worked. Not sure whether it is a good idea to put that

Comment: Explanation for [why `SET NOCOUNT ON` is needed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/235340/prb-error-messaging-referencing-temp-table-with-ado-sqloledb) may help